# Rolling aggegrates per date in pandas with duplicate date entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a dataset that contains the sale prices of different objects per day. What I would like to achieve is that for any given date in the dataset to compute the overall average for a fixed number of days preceding a sale (not including the sale date), ideally in a vectorized manner since the original dataset contains several million rows. The issue I'm faced with when using a conventional combination of a group by and rolling is that the aggregate numbers are different for the same date as illustrated below.

Setup

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": pd.date_range("2021-11-01", "2021-12-01").to_list()
        + pd.date_range("2021-11-01", "2021-12-01").to_list(),
        "price": ([31, 59, 60, 180, 16, 23, 90, 42, 70] * 7)[:-1],
    }
).sort_values(by="date").reset_index(drop=True)
```

Gives

```
    date    price
0   2021-11-01  31
1   2021-11-01  16
2   2021-11-02  59
3   2021-11-02  23
4   2021-11-03  60
... ... ...
57  2021-11-29  59
58  2021-11-30  90
59  2021-11-30  60
60  2021-12-01  180
61  2021-12-01  42
```

What I've been trying is different variations along the lines of

```py
df.set_index('date').rolling('3D', closed='right').mean()
```

Which gives the incorrect output, note the difference between the same-date values

```
    mean
date    
2021-11-01    31.000000
2021-11-01    23.500000
2021-11-02    35.333333
2021-11-02    32.250000
2021-11-03    37.800000
                ...    
2021-11-29    63.166667
2021-11-30    43.800000
2021-11-30    46.500000
2021-12-01    82.400000
2021-12-01    75.666667
```

The desired solution can be achieved with a non-vectorized approach by:

```py
df.date.map(dict(
    (
        x.date(),
        df[(df.date >= x - pd.Timedelta(days=3)) & (df.date < x)].price.mean(),
    )
    for x in pd.date_range(df.date.min(), df.date.max())
))
```

```
    mean
date    
2021-11-01  NaN
2021-11-01  NaN
2021-11-02  23.500000
2021-11-02  23.500000
2021-11-03  32.250000
... ...
2021-11-29  66.500000
2021-11-30  63.166667
2021-11-30  63.166667
2021-12-01  46.500000
2021-12-01  46.500000
```

Any ideas on how to leverage vector operations?

Answer (score 1):

2nd attempt - weighted averages
This is similar to your non-vectorized code, but performs slightly better on the small data set. It's not tested against real data, so unclear if it'll produce the results you want. (ie not averages of averages)

```
# calculate average price and number of occurrences for each date
dfn = df.groupby('date').agg(avgprice=('price','mean'), counts=('price', 'count'))

dfn['w_avg'] = 0.0

win = 3
end = dfn.shape[0]+1

# calculate a weighted average
for i in range(win, end, 1):
    dfr = dfn.iloc[i-win:i]
    wavg = (dfr['avgprice'] * dfr['counts']).sum() / dfr['counts'].sum()
    dfn.iat[i-win, 2] = wavg
    
dfn['w_avg'] = dfn['w_avg'].shift(win)
dfn

            avgprice  counts  w_avg
date
2021-11-01    23.500       2    NaN
2021-11-02    41.000       2    NaN
2021-11-03    75.000       2    NaN
2021-11-04   111.000       2 46.500
2021-11-05    43.000       2 75.667
2021-11-06    27.000       2 76.333
2021-11-07    74.500       2 60.333
2021-11-08    51.000       2 48.167
2021-11-09   125.000       2 50.833
2021-11-10    23.500       2 83.500
2021-11-11    41.000       2 66.500
2021-11-12    75.000       2 63.167
2021-11-13   111.000       2 46.500
2021-11-14    43.000       2 75.667
2021-11-15    27.000       2 76.333
2021-11-16    74.500       2 60.333
2021-11-17    51.000       2 48.167
2021-11-18   125.000       2 50.833
2021-11-19    23.500       2 83.500
2021-11-20    41.000       2 66.500
2021-11-21    75.000       2 63.167
2021-11-22   111.000       2 46.500
2021-11-23    43.000       2 75.667
2021-11-24    27.000       2 76.333
2021-11-25    74.500       2 60.333
2021-11-26    51.000       2 48.167
2021-11-27   125.000       2 50.833
2021-11-28    23.500       2 83.500
2021-11-29    41.000       2 66.500
2021-11-30    75.000       2 63.167
2021-12-01   111.000       2 46.500
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the rolling windows include previous members of the same day, you can use this less intuitive approach to calculate a closed 2-day interval, sample the last value from each day, and then join/merge those results with the *following* day.

```
totals_3day_window = df.set_index('date').rolling('2D', closed='both').mean().resample('D').agg(['last']).reset_index()
totals_3day_window['date'] = totals_3day_window['date'] + pd.Timedelta(days=1)
df.merge(totals_3day_window, on='date', how='left').rename(columns={('price', 'last'): 'avg_price_3_days'})

    date    price   avg_price_3_days
0   2021-11-01  31  NaN
1   2021-11-01  16  NaN
2   2021-11-02  59  23.500000
3   2021-11-02  23  23.500000
4   2021-11-03  60  32.250000
... ... ... ...
57  2021-11-29  59  66.500000
58  2021-11-30  90  63.166667
59  2021-11-30  60  63.166667
60  2021-12-01  180 46.500000
61  2021-12-01  42  46.500000
```

Comment: This should also work with other aggregate functions such as median.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the dates grouped. But if you want the rows from the original df, you can merge this back into the original dataset

```
df.set_index('date').groupby('date').mean().rolling('3D', closed='left').mean()

                price
date
2021-11-01        NaN
2021-11-02  23.500000
2021-11-03  32.250000
2021-11-04  46.500000
2021-11-05  75.666667
2021-11-06  76.333333
2021-11-07  60.333333
2021-11-08  48.166667
2021-11-09  50.833333
2021-11-10  83.500000
2021-11-11  66.500000
2021-11-12  63.166667
2021-11-13  46.500000
2021-11-14  75.666667
2021-11-15  76.333333
2021-11-16  60.333333
2021-11-17  48.166667
2021-11-18  50.833333
2021-11-19  83.500000
2021-11-20  66.500000
2021-11-21  63.166667
2021-11-22  46.500000
2021-11-23  75.666667
2021-11-24  76.333333
2021-11-25  60.333333
2021-11-26  48.166667
2021-11-27  50.833333
2021-11-28  83.500000
2021-11-29  66.500000
2021-11-30  63.166667
2021-12-01  46.500000
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! The issue with this approach is that it takes an average of an average, and since the number of data points per day varies, this approach is close but not exact, i.e.
```day_1 = np.array([2,2,2,2])
day_2 = np.array([8,8])
print(np.concatenate([day_1, day_2]).mean())
print(np.mean([day_1.mean(), day_2.mean()]))```